# enable prettyphoto on mobile

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, prettyphoto

I am using theme fusion's avada theme, where pretty photo lightbox is disabled for mobiles. I need to enable pretty photo lightbox on mobile. I have search on internet, but everywhere and everybody is requiring it to disable. Why it is so?

Please! any body help me to enable is back.

Thanks for great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have experienced the feature of lightbox for mobiles are disabled by Themefusion's team. You can get back this option by removing modernizr-min.js link from the header or removing the file.

Keep in mind! when you are not using modernizr-min, lightbox will appear very small on mobile devices. So you will have to restyle.

I hope it can help you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @offshore. Its very helpful. I was able to get it.